# Postman show the previous response

Tags: php, phpstorm, postman, opcache

I have installed Postman app on Ubuntu 18.4,

I have a problem with response, After change the code in PhpStorm IDE the response dose not change, I have cleared storage cache in Devtools but the issue still exist.

Now I found that after about 5 minutes Postman know that my changing code and update response. I haven't had this issue before.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you edit your code directly with PhpStorm, or you upload it with a deployment configuration? The question is: does the code actually change in the web root?

Answer (score 0):

After checking many way to solve this issue with supporting postman guys in [Postman github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5321) , I found my Problem ,

> I have enabled recently [opcache](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi3rpTcxfbdAhUmDMAKHaY_Cs8QFjAAegQICRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.opcache.php&usg=AOvVaw1hePlGoB6eTih21pBFUdGL) in php7.2 and this caused the problem. after disabling it,problem solved.